# How to make login in django through a different table than auth_users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, authentication, django-models

Not sure what I am doing wrong I will leave below my files. The register method works perfectly but when I am doing the login, everytime the output is `user is none.`

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

I read the documentation of authentication with django but I cannot spot the problem. I saw that there were some questions about this problem, but I couldn't solve mine.
**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', views.registerMethod, name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginMethod, name="login"),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), 
]
```

**views.py**

```
def registerMethod(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('firstname') and request.POST.get('lastname') and request.POST.get('password'):
            user = NewUser()
            user.first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
            user.last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
            user.password = request.POST.get('password')
            user.email = request.POST.get('email')
            password =  user.password.encode('utf-8')
            # Hash the ecoded password and generate a salt: 
            hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(10))
            
            user.password = str(hashedPassword)
            user.first_name = CleanString(user.first_name)
            user.last_name = CleanString(user.last_name)
            user.email = CleanString(user.email)
            message = None
            if UserExistsByEmail(user.email):
                message = 'You are already registered!'
                return render(request, 'register/register.html', {"message":message})
            else:
                user.save()
                message = 'You have succesfully created an account!'
                return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"message":message})
        else:
            return render(request, 'register/register.html')
    else:
            return render(request, 'register/register.html')

def loginMethod(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate( email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            message = 'You are logged in!'
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"message":message})
        else:
            message = 'user is None!'
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"message":message})
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class NewUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='noUsername')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    is_super_user = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
    def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py`. Django has to know which "User" your project is using.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.NewUser'
```

But you don't want your `NewUser` to be `models.Model`, it should be `AbstractUser` or another `CustomUser` class. Before you go any further, please read some [official docs about User customization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: I did everything you mentioned.. But know when I click on login now, it redirects me to `'register/register.html`... I set `return redirect('/')` to get me on the home page, but it still took me on register.html. Any idea why? something is not working well?

Comment: You have to also set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'your_homepage_or_whatever'` and `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` in settings.

Comment: I had that: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "https://google.com"
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/" ` but still drive me to /register. And the login works only on this workflow: 1. I did register 2. I enter credentials from register (It takes me to register page). Then If I go back on login page, I get the same issue `user is none`

Comment: I think I will try to do the process from 0 again.. Not sure what I missed.

Comment: The problem was the following one: I didn't rewrite the userManager class for my case.